# How do I count the number of specific letters within a word?

Tags: python, string

I have a lot of text, and I need to clasify them to find out the number of letters in a joint word.
For example:

```
aabbccccdde
```

I want it to show a result like:

```
a 2
b 2
c 4
d 2
e 1
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
word = 'aabbccccdde'
d = {l:word.count(l) for l in set(word)}

for key in sorted(d):
   print(key, d[key])
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter('aabbccccdde')
# c now looks like Counter({'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 4, 'd': 2, 'e': 1})
```